# Save a line chart to Excel

Tags: python

I am new to python and have a code to plot values of two python lists to a line plot using openpyxl. It works fine and produce nice plot but can not save the plot to the excel file or sheet. Any help will be highly appreciated

I am using the following code

```
plt.title('PHID / PHIN Crossover')
plt.plot(pn, dpt, color='red', marker='', label='PHIN')
plt.plot(pd, dpt, color='blue', marker='', label='PHIN')
plt.xlabel('Porosity')
plt.ylabel('Depth')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.legend(['PHIN', 'PHID'])
#ws1.add_chart("Line Chart", 'H1')
plt.show()
wb.save(fnm) #you have to save it for the file to appear in directory
```

and getting the following Error Message

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\modified plot.py", line 87, in 
ws1.add_chart("Line Chart", 'H1')
File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 550, in add_chart
chart.anchor = anchor
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'anchor'

Answer (score 0):

As an immediate workaround, if you're trying to save the figure that is generated into an excel file, you could try:

```
plt.savefig("<path_to_save>/image.png")
```

Then import the image into a spreadsheet from the Excel workbook interface or even just copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to create a plot using matplotlib and directly saving that plot into an excel file, you can use the below code. Added some comments to make it easier. This will create a random dataframe, use the code you have to draw lineplot and load the file into an excel file with name MyImageFile.xlsx, sheet Line Chart and cell H1. Hope this is what you are looking for

```
import xlsxwriter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io

#Random data for my image
pn = np.random.randint(14,18, size=(10))
pd = np.random.randint(4, 8, size=(10))
dpt = np.arange(10)

#Create graph
plt.title('PHID / PHIN Crossover')
plt.plot(pn, dpt, color='red', marker='', label='PHIN')
plt.plot(pd, dpt, color='blue', marker='', label='PHIN')
plt.xlabel('Porosity')
plt.ylabel('Depth')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.legend(['PHIN', 'PHID'])

#Open Work book and select sheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('MyImageFile.xlsx')
ws=workbook.add_worksheet('Line Chart')
#ws.write(0,0,'test')

#Insert data in excel file directly without needing to save as a picture file
imgdata=io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(imgdata, format='png')
ws.insert_image(1,8, '', {'image_data': imgdata}) #For cell H1
workbook.close()
```